# Classic ASP Server CreateObject

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have zero knowledge of classic ASP and unfortunately I have been given the task of getting a legacy .net webforms/classic asp site up and running. I am almost there (I think) however I am getting an error on this line

```
set objAppContext = Server.CreateObject( "P21Dat.AppContext" )
```

Here is the error

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 8007007e'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/siteconfig.asp, line 71

8007007e
```

I have no idea what "P21Dat.AppContext" is any help?

Comment: Is this component installed? It have necessary permission?

Comment: More likely the component is not registered with `regsvr32`

Comment: What is P21Dat.AppContext supposed to do?  Could it be a custom component which a previous developer compiled in VB6

Answer (score 2):

99.99% that ActiveX "P21Dat.AppContext" not registered on your machine.

0.01% that you don't have permission ;)

You could try to find in in registry...

You could use OleView program (or "Ole-Com Object Viewer" program) to get information about this ActiveX component...

Comment: I would go for 50/50 and not 99.99/0.01, I think it all depends on your habitat...

Comment: another possibility is that it's 32 bit and 32 bit applications haven't been enabled in the app pool.  Presumably the site once ran on an earlier version of IIS than 7.5

Answer (score 1):

Even after uninstalling and re-installing it several times, my dll wasn't picked up by my ASP application.
I can clearly see it in Registry list. I even gave permission to that key to everyone but no go.

After several tries I found it was because my dll was on network drive. 
I copied to my local machine, un-installed and re-installed from local drive and it started working.